# Bit stream saved as uint8_t in C

Tags: c, arrays, bit-manipulation

(EDITED: added whole working code) I have 24 bits stored as a string. I'm using C and I want to store each set of 8 bits, starting at position 0, as an element of a `uint8_t` array. I've tried different things to no avail. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define SIZE 24 

char byte(int n, char data[])
{
    char substr[8];

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i ++)
    {
        substr[i] = data[i + n*8];
    }

    return substr[0];
}

int main (void)
{
    uint8_t send[3] = { 0 };
    char data[] = "101010101010100100000000";

    printf ("Data is = %s\n", data);

    for ( int i = 0; i < SIZE/8; i++)
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            send[i] |= (data[j+8*i] == '1') << (7-j); 
        }
        printf("%d\n",send[i]);
    }

    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: `send[SIZE/8];` is `send[1];`  It that intended?

Comment: BTW `uint8_t send` isn't initialized properly. Well, it lacks a [mcve] anyway.

Comment: Perhaps `(7-i);` --> `(7-j);`

Comment: @XaimeRR there is no main, and your data isn't initialized.

Comment: @chux Thank you. Couldn't see what was right in front of me!

Comment: Or use the strtol function which can take a base parameter (2) in your case.

Comment: You are calling `printf` on your uint8_t array members, but treating them as ints with `%d`.  I wanna say `%hhu` would be what you want to use.

Comment: I know the decimal representation so it doesn't matter to me, it was the fastest way to debug my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you do not intialize `send`, such that a `send[i] |= ...` may add something to "garbage" (actually it is undefined behaviour, but probably just garbage).
So write `uint8_t send[SIZE/8] = { 0 };`

Second, it's a typo, as it should be `7-j` (instead of `7-i`), i.e. `(data[j+8*i] == '1') << (7-j);`

Comment: Actually send is declared at global scope so it's seemingly initilaized to zeros.  I take it back, now he's added a `main(...)` it's no longer global

Answer (score 1):

Since you're only looping `for ( int i = 0; i < SIZE/8; i++)` from 0 less than 1

```
send[i] |= (data[j+8*i] == '1') << (7-i);
```

Change it to

```
send[i] |= (data[j+8*i] == '1') << (7-j);
```

Comment: And add before j loop send[i] =0;

Comment: @PeterJ_01 He's edited the question.  I was assuming both send and data were at global scope.